# Topological graphs

Tags: general-topology

I am studying graph theory from perspective of topology. Wikipedia says that topological graph is a topological space constructed from regular graph by replacing vertices with points and edges with intervals. I am not sure what are intervals. I suppose that these are some kind of topological space and I've read that they are called *manifolds*. I've read also that topological homeomorphism is equivalent to topological graph isomorphism. And I kinda understand, but can you, please, clarify, can edges of such graph intersect with each other. Because I feel that two intervals that intersect is not the same topological space. So, how can I understand this? Thank you in advance!

Edit:
And another question. Am I mistaken when I said that homemorphism of surfaces is equivalent to graph homeomorphism? So, can we from isomorphism of two topological graphs (there I mean homeomorphism) assert that two surfaces are equivalent?

Comment: This question would benefit from some more context and clarity. In particular, the terminology of "topological graph" and "topological graph isomorphism" are, I would say, ambiguous. By interval, they mean the space $[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Topological graphs (in any reasonable interpretation of that term) are not always manifolds.

Comment: @Thorgott I only know about graphs from this article: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_graph_theory#Graphs_as_topological_spaces). I don't know exactly what is manifold, but I know that it is topological space. Lets consider this.

Comment: I've written an answer to a couple of your most focussed questions, but I also suggest you read one of our important guidelines: please [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common in topology to take an archetypal topological space --- for example ***THE*** interval $[0,1]$ --- and then borrow that terminology, using an indefinite adjective, to represent any homeomorphic topological space. Thus we have:

> An interval is a topological space homemorphic to the interval $[0,1]$.

There are other common examples of this, for instance circles and spheres.

Your post continues with a bunch of other questions which get quickly get out of focus, so I will close by addressing only the most focussed of them. A topological graph does indeed contain a specified collection of intervals (meaning, according to the definition above, subspaces each of which is homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$). These specified intervals are themselves still called the *edges* of the graph. It is indeed possible for two edges $E_1,E_2$ of a graph to intersect each other, but that is *only* possible if the intersection $E_1 \cap E_2$ consists of a single point $p$, and that point $p$ must be an endpoint of the interval $E_1$, and it must also be an endpoint of the interval $E_2$.